# Entero a Fecha - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

Tengo una duda, en PHP puedo convertir un numero entero a fecha, de la siguiente manera:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i",'1544102153');
```

y retorna:

```
2018-12-06 14:15
```

Como puedo hacer esto en Angular? he intentado con:

```
{{'1544102153' | date:'dd/MM/yyyy(EEE) - hh:mmaaa'}}
```

Pero me retorna:

```
18/01/1970(Sun) - 06:03PM
```

Gracias por la Ayuda.

Comment: Recoge la fecha en el component.ts, transformalo a Date y ponle el formato que quieras, después con el data-bindin pásalo al front

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Javascript (y por tanto también en Typescript) se trabaja con milisegundos:

```js
const d1 = new Date(1544102153);

console.log('Fecha:',d1);

const d2 = new Date(1544102153 *1000);

console.log('Fecha pasando de segundos a milisegundos', d2);
```

Así que lo que tienes que hacer es multiplicar por 1000 tu número.